# Recursive formula for 2D Bernstein Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, approximation, bezier-curve

So for a 3D-Modelling exercise we need to create a smooth model, using Bezier surfaces. Now I've learned the recursive definition of a 1D Bezier curve, using this formula, where $P:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3; t\mapsto(x,y,z)$

$$ P_i^{(j)}(t) =  (1-t)P_{i-1}^{(j-1)} + tP_{i}^{(j-1)}$$

So how do I go from this formula to a recursive formula in two dimensions?
So $S:[0,1]^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3;(u,v)\mapsto(x,y,z)$
I saw some [definitions](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF3320/h03/undervisningsmateriale/lecture8.pdf) (Page 16), which are non recursive, but I can't seem to make any sense of it

Comment: Note that the basis polynomials are products of the one dimensional polynomials, so there is an obvious recursive relation found by iterating each of the one dimensional recursion relations, that looks like $ B_{i,j}^{d_1,d_2}(u,v) = (1-u) (1-v) B_{i-1,j-1}^{d_1-1,d_2-1} + (1-u) v B_{i-1,j}^{d_1-1,d_2-1} +  u (1-v) B_{i,j-1}^{d_1-1,d_2-1} +B_{i,j}^{d_1-1,d_2-1} $. This will also give a generalization of de Casteljau's algorithm.

Comment: Did you forget to add an $uv$ before the $B_{i,j}^{d_1-1,d_2-1}$?
If so, please change it, and make it to $uvB_{i,j}^{d_1-1,d_2-1}$. If you post it as a full answer I can give you reputation for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a de Casteljau algorithm for tensor product (rectangular) surfaces on [this web page](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/surface/bezier-de-casteljau.html).

But there's nothing magic about recursive formulae, and they're harder to understand and implement. If you fix the surface degree (to $3 \times 3$, for example). Then you can write explicit formulas for the basis function:
\begin{align}
B_0(t) &= (1-t)^3  \\
B_1(t) &= 3t(1-t)^2   \\
B_2(t) &= 3t^2(1-t)   \\
B_3(t) &= t^3   \\
\end{align}

Then plug these into the surface equations on page 16 of your notes.